# InstallShield Limited Edition 2015 warning -6245 .Net Framework required

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, installshield

I've created a project using VS2015, it uses .net framework v4.6.1.
I'm now trying to create an install program for it using InstallShield Limited Edition.  When I compile the install shield package I get the following warning :

ISEXP : warning -6245: One or more of the project's components contain .NET properties that require the .NET Framework.  It is recommended that the release include the .NET Framework.

With the limited edition I don't see the option to include the .net framework, nor do I see a way to make the .net framework v4.6.1 a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

in the section - Specify Application Data -> Redistributables 
you can select the .net framework v4.6 to be included with your program.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer had a negative vote. It's simple and to the point. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

While Installshield LE does support including .NET 4.6, it does not support including .NET 4.6.1.
When my programs is run for the first time, the user is prompted to install it and it works fine. I simply document that this may happen the first time the user runs the program.